# Writing a simple quiz, how to access the choices that are defined in a variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, indexing

Probably something very basic but I'm trying to write a simple JS quiz, and I have an array for the questions, choices and answers all in one:

```
const questions = [
  {
    question: "What is JavaScript?",
    choices: ["An interesting coffee blend", "Something your doctor uses", "A new movie", "A coding language"],
    answer: 3
  },
  {
    question: "Which of the following keywords is used to define a variable?",
    choices: ["var", "let", "Both A and B", "None of the above"],
    answer: 2
  },
```

etc..

I can choose a specific question from the array, but not the relevant choices or answers from that.

```
function grabQuestion() {
  for (let i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    const question = questions[i].question
    const choices = questions[i].choices
    questionEl.textContent = question
    console.log(choices)
    console.log(answer)
  }
}
```

This just lists the all of the questions.choices not the index that I've generated in the for loop.

I know it's simple but I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: double quoted strings can't have line-breaks in between them, without escaping it with a backslash. Your example is syntactically invalid.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  You're looping through the array of "question" objects, setting the `textContent` of an element, and logging two values to the console (one of which doesn't appear to be defined anywhere).  What exactly isn't working?

Comment: If you want your function `grabQuestion` to return/log/set one specific question - then you should not loop over _all_ questions, but pass the index of the question that you are looking for, as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, You want to fetch a `choices` and `answer` of the specific question instead to get all the answer and choices ? If Yes, Then you can get that dynamically from the array based on the question `text` or by assigning an `id` to each question object.

Let me explain that with an example/demo **:**

```js
const questions = [
{
  question: "What is JavaScript?",
  choices: ["An interesting coffee blend", "Something your doctor uses", "A new movie", "A coding language"],
  answer: 3
},
{
  question: "Which of the following keywords is used to define a variable?",
  choices: ["var", "let", "Both A and B", "None of the above"],
  answer: 2
}];

function getQuestionDetails(questionText) {
  return questions.find(({ question }) => questionText === question);
}

const selectedQuestionDetails = getQuestionDetails('What is JavaScript?');

console.log('choices', selectedQuestionDetails.choices);

console.log('answer', selectedQuestionDetails.answer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to define `answer` I think.
Just add this.

```
const answer = questions[i].answer
```

Comment: Sorry I should've the console.log, that was just me testing. When I do that it returns all the answers, not just of the question thats being returned with the for loop. What I want is the coinciding choice/answer to the specific question. I thought by adding the index to the variable this would work as opposed to just questions.choices. Cheers though I'm not communicating efficiently should just put it down for today lol.